# Ajax call not successful

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am making a javascript function call on onclick of any checkbox like this:

```
function getPGCountList(pageNo) {
    var url = "someJsp.jsp?" + pageNo;
    alert(1);
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        alert(2);
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        alert(3);
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    alert(4);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        alert(5);
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            alert(6);
            document.getElementById("searchForPage").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    alert(7);
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    alert(8);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

The alert output I am getting is at my hosted site:

```
1-2-4-7-5-8-5-5-5
```

But in my local system it is:

```
1-2-4-7-5-8-5-5-5-6
```

I need to execute alert 6 also to change the content.
I am not sure where is the problem?

Comment: java != javascript, don't tag as both.

Comment: I also don't see any jQuery, was that tag a mistake too, or are you accepting jQuery answers?

Comment: Did you look at the request in your browser's dev tools?

Comment: is someJsp.jsp in the same path as the page executing this code on the hosting site, could be you are getting a 404, as jason p mentions check your dev tools network tab to see what is being return for that call.

Comment: Path I am giving is correct one. Its running correctly in my local system, The same thing I have copied there.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine to me.  Check the path to someJsp.jsp
It's obviously not returning a normal response from the ajax call otherwise it would enter your if block and fire alert 6.

Just a thought too, but if you alert xmlhttp.readyState and xmlhttp.status maybe it'll help you find your problem.  IF they are undefined, or refer to an object that is undefined, then your new XMLHttp requests failed.  IF they give you results, you can see what the responses mean

Comment: How can I get/verify what is the response?

Comment: Some more info xmlhttp.readyState and xmlhttp.status combination is 1-0 then 2-500 then 3-500 then at last 4-500.